# Как передать url в массив с результатами ( curl_multi_getcontent )

Tags: php

Есть такой скрипт:

```
$urls = []; //в этом массиве будет множество url вида https://site1.ru, https://newsite.ru

$multiCurl = array();
$result = array();
$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    $fetchURL = $url;
    $multiCurl[$i] = curl_init();
    .......
}
$index=null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh,$index);
} while($index > 0);
foreach($multiCurl as $k => $ch) {
    $result[$k] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

И тут я получаю в массив **$result** html всех сайтов которые были в массиве `$urls`.

Мне нужно чтобы в массив **$result** так же передавался url к которому относиться этот html.

В идеале чтобы **$result** был такого вида:

```
(0) 'https://site1.ru' => html
(1) 'https://newsite.ru' => html
```

Comment: дак и используйте `$multiCurl[$url]` вместо `[$i]` при инициализации

Comment: @teran точно! Спасибо огромное)) что-то не подумал...